# show that a measure is complete

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

If $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ is a measure space and $\mathcal{\overline{M}}:=\{E\cup F:E\in\mathcal{M}\text{ and }F\subset N\text{ for some }N\in \mathcal{N}\}$ is a completion of $\mathcal{M}$ with respect to $\mu$ where $\mathcal{N}:=\{N\in\mathcal{M}:\mu(N)=0\},$ then $\mathcal{\overline{M}}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

If now $\overline{\mu}(E\cup F):=\mu(E)$ how to show that $\overline{\mu}$ is a complete measure?

I suspect that we need to show that any subset of a null-set is measurable.

Comment: can you show that it is a measure? ignore completeness for the moment.

Comment: I need to show countable additivity i. e if $E_{1},E_{2},,,,\in\mathcal{\overline{M}}$ and $\displaystyle\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_{n}\in\mathcal{\overline{M}}$ then $\overline{\mu}(\displaystyle\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_{n})=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\overline{\mu}(E_{n})$

Comment: Is it obvious this is well-defined btw? If $A = E\cup F = E'\cup F'$, then does it follow that $\mu(E) = \mu(E')$?

Comment: it is well defined, since if $E_{1}\cup F_{1}=E_{2}\cup F_{2}$ where $F_{j}\subset N_{j}\in\mathcal{N}$ then $E_{1}\subset E_{2}\cup N_{2}$ and so $\mu(E_{1})\le \mu(E_{2})+\mu(N_{2})=\mu(E_{2})$ and likewise $\mu(E_{2})\le \mu(E_{1})$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Complete just means that if $A$ is a measurable set with $\overline{\mu} A = 0$, and $B \subset A$, then $\overline{\mu} B = 0$ also.

Suppose $A \in \overline{M}$ such that $\overline{\mu} A = 0$. Then $A = E \cup F$,
where $E \in M$ and $F \subset N$, with $N \in {\cal N}$. Since $\overline{\mu} A = 0$, we have $\mu E = 0$ also. In particular, $A \subset E \cup N$, and $\mu(E \cup N) = 0$.

Now suppose $B \subset A$. The we can write $B = \emptyset \cup B$, and $B \subset E \cup N$, where $E \cup N \in {\cal N}$. Hence $B \in \overline{M}$, and $\overline{\mu} B = \mu \emptyset  = 0$.

Comment: Excellent answer. It was exactly what I was after. Helped a lot to understand the concept of completeness itself. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to be of help!